# Java android AutocompleteView inside AsyncTask not showing dropdown

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, autocompletetextview

I am trying to do an automcompleteView inside an asynctask and the dropdown selection is not working. If I do it the regular way inside the Oncreate method then it works such as this

```
// onCreate with no Async
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.housing);

    homes = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.housing);
    homes.setThreshold(1);

    String[] check= {"Rent", "House"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapters= new ArrayAdapter<>
  (mylist.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, check);
    homes.setAdapter(adapters);
}
```

The code above works perfectly so now I attempt to put it inside an AsyncTask and nothing happens no error and the dropdownList does not work as I type in the Textbox. I have looked at other examples on this website but nothing seems to work this is my Async...

```
// onCreate with Async
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.housing);

    homes = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.housing);
    homes.setThreshold(1);

    homes.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!homes.isPopupShowing()) {
                homes.showDropDown();
            }
            nemo task = new nemo();
            task.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                         int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

// Async

private class nemo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /*
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url;
    */
    String line,libo = "";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String  doInBackground(String[] jsonData) {
        libo = "homes";

        return libo;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String[] results) {
        String[] check= {"Rent", "House"};
        homes = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.housing);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapters= new ArrayAdapter<>
  (mylist.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, check);
        homes.setAdapter(adapters);
        homes.showDropDown();
    }
}
```

The AsyncTask will eventually get data from the database but for right now I simply want to reproduce the same results as the first example with onCreate and No Async.

Comment: Did you try to track down the problem with some logging? Which callback is not getting invoked exactly? Also, just a guess - try to comment out `homes.showDropDown()` in `onTextChanged()`.

Comment: Thanks I just commented that out and strangely it started working